# DateTime::createFromFormat issue on server , works in local machine

Tags: php, timestamp

Problem while converting time entered by user to unix timestamp , it is working in the local machine and not working in the server .

This is the code am using , can anybody help please !!!

for delivery_date_time

```
$d = str_replace('-', ',', $delivery_date);
$t = str_replace(':', ',', $delivery_time);
$date = $t.',0,'.$d;
$fulldate = explode(',',$date);

$h = $fulldate[0];
$i = $fulldate[1];
$s = $fulldate[2];
$y = $fulldate[3];
$m =$fulldate[4];
$d = $fulldate[5];
$dst = 0;

$date_delivery = date("h:ia d/m/Y",mktime($h,$i,$s,$m,$d,$y,$dst));
$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia d/m/Y',$date_delivery );
$timestamp_delivery_datetime = $objDate->getTimestamp();
$human_readable_date = date('d/m/Y h:ia',$timestamp_delivery_datetime);
```

The code works and can be used for converting dates to Unix timestamp and vice versa.  The issue was with the version of PHP I was using in the server.  Just upgraded the PHP version from 5.2 to 5.4.

Comment: And what is the problem precisely? Does it give you any error messages? Does it create incorrect dates?

Comment: What do you get, what errors are there, what do you expect, what's the input you were parsing? We can't reproduce anything without the same input you use - you provided insufficient information. Also why use `mktime` and date if you are using `DateTime`?

Comment: Note that `H` !== `h`, which could explain if your error is a 24-hr/12-hr error

Comment: I am using this with AJAX and the execution stops if i use DateTime::createFromFormat , is this usage correct ???  I mean the entire syntax .       "$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia d/m/Y',$date_delivery );"

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 in local machine and the live server is having PHP Version 5.2.17 . Will this be the problem ???

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat() requires PHP >= 5.3.0 (as you'd know if you read the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)), and you should also have got an error telling you that this class/method doesn't exist.... and why are you developing on 5.5 but running live on 5.2?

Comment: Will it be a problem? Yes it will. Get that live server upgraded! Now! PHP 5.2 has been completely unsupported since January 2011 -- it is riddled with security holes. It also has loads of stuff missing, including lots of bug fixes and new features. In particular, the `createFromFormat` method was only introduced in PHP 5.3, so your 5.2 server won't understand it. Upgrade now.

Comment: problem solved .upgraded to PHP  version 4  Thank you for your suggestions .

Comment: uh, that'll be version **5.4** rather than version 4, right????!!!!  :-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that your live server is running PHP 5.2. This is your problem.

PHP 5.2 does not include the `DateTime::createFromFormat()` function. This function was only introduced in PHP 5.3. See the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for confirmation of this.

Your code will not be able to run under PHP 5.2.

PHP 5.2 is very badly obsolete, so the only recommendation I can give you is to upgrade as soon as possible. Aside from all the missing functionality, you're also putting yourself at severe risk of a hack by running such an old an unsupported PHP version.

The current minimum supported version of PHP is 5.4, but if possible you should straight up to 5.5 or 5.6, especially since you're using 5.5 already as your development base.